# Converting xts objects from FRED to data.table

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, xts

I have an xts object from FRED, and would like to convert it to a data.table (or a dataframe) object instead. The relevant code is:

```
library(data.table)
library(quantmod)
library(Quandl)
library(zoo)
library(knitr)
library(ggplot2)

dataTableTemp <- getSymbols('DJIA', src='FRED')
dataTableTemp <- as.data.table(dataTableTemp)
```

And this is the content of the xts object it gets:

```
             DJIA
2007-08-08   13657.86
2007-08-09   13270.68
2007-08-10   13239.54
...          ...
```

str(DJIA), which is the name it is given when it downloads, gives

```
> str(DJIA)
An ‘xts’ object on 2007-08-08/2017-08-08 containing:
  Data: num [1:2610, 1] 13658 13271 13240 13237 13029 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr "DJIA"
  Indexed by objects of class: [Date] TZ: UTC
  xts Attributes:  
List of 2
 $ src    : chr "FRED"
 $ updated: POSIXct[1:1], format: "2017-08-09 09:41:49"
```

It goes on like that for a few thousand rows. When I convert it to a data.table with the second line of code, however, this is all that there is (in a table format):

```
             dataTableTemp
1            DJIA
```

I've tried using `fortify(dataTableTemp)` from ggplot2, in addition to

`dataTableTemp <- data.frame(date=index(dataTableTemp), coredata(dataTableTemp))`, and even the `tribble()` method, but none of them seem to work. What should I do to convert it to a dataframe/data.table?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: When that executes, dataTableTemp only has one row with a 'date' and a 'coredata.dataTableTemp' column. The 'date' is just the number 1 (which is obviously not correct), and the other column is the ticker name (DJIA), when it should be a number like 16000.

Comment: Do it on DJIA, not on dataTableTemp? Which is probably just the string name of the symbol returned. Assignment for get symbols returns the name by default. There is an argument you can set to return the data in the assignment, but your global env gets DJIA

Comment: dataTableTemp <- data.frame(date=index(DJIA), coredata(DJIA))

Comment: That works! Thank you so much! I ended up using the get function and I had a typo in the setnames function. Now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So that others know how this issue was solved:

```
getSymbols('DJIA', src='FRED') 
dataTableTemp <- as.data.table(DJIA)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the result you expect, if you adjust the `auto.assign` parameter in `getSymbols`:

```
# Note the auto.assign = FALSE parameter specification (this will avoid assigning the data to JDIA in the global environment.:

dataTableTemp <- getSymbols('DJIA', src='FRED', auto.assign = FALSE)
x = data.table("date" = index(dataTableTemp), coredata(dataTableTemp))
```